# jquery clone and append table inside <li>

Tags: jquery

i want clone table "test-tab" then append it inside tag li of ul "list-tab".

```
<table id="test-tab">......</table>
<ul id="list-tab">

</ul>
```

this is my jquery code not work:

```
$("#list-tab").append("<li>"+$("#test-tab").clone()+"</li>");
```

i want result like this:

```
<table id="test-tab">......</table>
<ul id="list-tab">
<li><table id="test-tab">......</table></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't concat jquery object with string, use this

```
$("#list-tab").append( $("<li></li>").append($("#test-tab").clone()) );
```

Comment: There will be a little check mark next to each answer, under the vote tally. Just click it and you've accepted the answer. @toasang
look this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91889/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-to-my-questions and I recommend you to take a satckoverflow tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour